# How is the .pop() method able to redefine a variable by only being the value of another?

Tags: python, methods

So in python if you create your `list`, then a new variable, `reject_list` and assign it the `.pop()` method, it changes the value in the previous `list` variable.

```
list = ['item', 'thing', 'piece']
reject_list = list.pop()
print(list)

['item', 'thing']
```

I understand this effect, but not how it's possible. How does assigning the method of one variable as the value of another retroactively change the value of the original variable without first being defined, like this:

```
list = ['item', 'thing', 'piece']
list = list.pop()    
print(list)

['item', 'thing']
```

For instance, this doesn't work with the `.title()` method:

```
name = mike 
new_name = name.title() 
print(name)

mike
#the original name did not capitalize
```

so how is the .pop() method able to redefine a variable by only being the value of another?

Comment: `title()` returns a copy of the String in which first characters of all the words are capitalized.

Comment: You probably want to avoid using the name `list`, as it's a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation of what you're seeing is not correct. The change in the value of `list` has nothing to do with you assigning the result of `list.pop()` to `reject_list`.

Python is an object-based language which means the basic element of data in it are *objects*, which are a collection of data (or *state*) and functions (called *methods*). Methods can access the state contained in the object they are called on and they can modify it. In the case of list, its elements are its state. The behaviour of `pop()` is to modify this state by removing the last element of the list it was called on and returning it. Therefore, after calling it, the original list is shorter by one element.

Have a look at this example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a          # the name "b" refers to the same list as the name "a"
>>> a.pop()        # we pop off a value but don't assign it anywhere
3
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> b
[1, 2]
```

Note that the result of `a.pop()` isn't assigned to anything but `a` is still changed. You can think of the meaning of `a.pop()` as "remove the last element of the list a (while also returning it as a result)".

Also note that it is not a good idea to use the name `list` since it is a builtin identifier referring to the list type itself and you are redefining it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with Python, so i'm definitely lacking in the right vocabulary to ask my question right. I understand your example, because there's a variable being redefined on it's own, on line 3.
But, pop() doesn't need that, it can be placed into the value of another variable, and at the same time alter the original variable. Like, the upper() method can be placed in the value of another variable, and leave the original intact:
a = 'hey'
b = a.upper()
print(a)
print(b)
    -> hey
    ->HEY
But pop() doesn't do that, does that make sense? I'm sorry, thank you for your help

Comment: `pop` and `upper` aren't placed into another variable. They are called on some object `a` with the syntax `a.pop()` or `a.upper()` and that tells them to calculate their result and return it. Their *result* is then either placed into another variable or you can decide not to (this is the difference between `b = a.pop()` and `b.pop()`). The difference between them is that `upper` is a *pure* function, which means it leaves the original value intact, simply using it to calculate a new value. `pop`, on the other hand, explicitly changes the original value (by removing its final element).

Comment: Also, the variable is *not* being redefined on line 3, only the object it is referring to is being changed (mutated). In Python, names (variables) are distinct from the objects they are referring to. The point in that example is that both names, `a` and `b` refer to the **same** object which exists independently of the names.

Comment: I also realised you may also be after a method that will return the last element of a list *without* modifying the list. Then `pop` is simply not the method to use and you can do `a[-1]` instead.

Comment: Ahhhh, I didn't know that there were pure and not pure functions, so .pop() isn't this weird standalone thing, it's just the only one i've encountered so far. And yes, [-1] is really the more helpful variant of what I was looking for!

Comment: Speaking as someone who loves Haskell, it's actually rather refreshing to see someone uncorrupted by external expectations expect pure functions to be the default. Glad I could help.

Comment: @Mike, also, if you find your question is resolved, you should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the `list.pop()` method specifically modifies the object; **removes** and returns an item from the list. `str.title()` returns a *version* of the string in title case, but does not modify the string itself.

It's also noteworthy that strings are immutable in Python.

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
popped_element = my_list.pop()
print(my_list)
#['a', 'b']
print(popped_element)
#'c'
```